# jQuery variable as iframe URL

Tags: jquery, forms, variables

Why isn't this script working?

```
$(function() {
    var isbn = $('input').val();
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#data").html('<iframe height="500" width="1000" src="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN' + isbn + '" />');
    });
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do an extremely simple ISBN lookup field for a demo web site. The script is supposed to take the value of the input and insert it into the URL. Why isn't it working?

Also, is there a better way to accomplish this end?

I realize, of course, that iframes are rubbish, but I just want to keep it simple right now.

Comment: What isn't working?  If you build the URL as a separate variable and alert() it beforehand, does it show up as you expect?  Are you getting an js errors from Firebug (you *are* using Firebug, right ;)?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Does ISBN return a value or does the url the IFrame points to not have the GET Parameters at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear when your code gets called, but is this line:

```
var isbn = $('input').val();
```

only called once at page-load time, whereas it should be within the click handler:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var isbn = $('input').val();
    $("#data").html('<iframe height="500" width="1000" src="http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN' + isbn + '" />');
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something obvious like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not load the page you wanted to view through the ajax load technique, so fetching the html and displaying it within the element:

```
$(function() {
    var isbn = $('input').val();
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#data").load('http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN' + isbn);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not your code but its the query string you have.

please amend as follows and it should work:

```
var isbn = "1603038159";

        $("#data").html('<iframe height="500" width="600" src="http://books.google.com/books?as_isbn=' + isbn);
```